# Pandas equivalent of reshape2 acast

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse

I have a dataset of some time series data that looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(location = c('f1','f1','f1','f1'),
             year = c('1999','1999','1999','1999'),
             day = c('01-01','01-02','01-01','01-02'),
             variable = c('var1','var1','var2','var2'),
             value = c(1.0, 3.0, "option1","option2"))
```

In R, I can transform this such that I have this kind of data structure where I use location + year as 1 axis, day as another, and my variable as the third, with `reshape2::acast`:

```
> reshape2::acast(df, location + year ~ day ~ variable)
, , var1

        01-01 01-02
f1_1999 "1"   "3"  

, , var2

        01-01     01-02    
f1_1999 "option1" "option2"
```

How can I achieve the same effect with a Pandas dataframe? My first attempt was using `pivot` or `pivot_table` but I think I'm misunderstanding how they work: `pandas.pivot_table(df, index = ['location','year'], columns = 'day', values = 'variable')` produces the error `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. Given a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'location': ['f1','f1','f1','f1'],
    'year': ['1999','1999','1999','1999'],
    'day': ['01-01','01-02','01-01','01-02'],
    'variable': ['var1','var1','var2','var2'],
    'value': [1.0, 3.0, 'option1','option2']
})
```

Is there any way to achieve the same data structure in R (with something like numpy arrays)?

Comment: Would be helpful to see your expected output as a DataFrame. Can that be arranged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will reshape your data into a MultiIndexed DataFrame, which is one way to work with > 2D data in pandas. Note the changing of `aggfunc` - normally it defaults to a numeric aggregation, that lambda just passes through data unchanged.

```
res = df.pivot_table(index=['location', 'year'], 
                     columns=['variable', 'day'], 
                     values='value', 
                     aggfunc=lambda x: x)
res
Out[7]: 
variable       var1           var2         
day           01-01 01-02    01-01    01-02
location year                              
f1       1999     1     3  option1  option2
```

From there, see the [MultiIndexing docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) for more.  E.g., to select out `day == '01-02'`

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice   
res.loc[:, idx[:, '01-02']]

Out[12]: 
variable       var1     var2
day           01-02    01-02
location year               
f1       1999     3  option2
```

Comment: This is perfect! After playing with it a bit, I think the structure I'm looking for is flipped, like:

    `df.pivot_table(index = ['variable','day'], columns = ['location','year'], values = 'value', aggfunc = lambda x: x)`

But I think the empty `aggfunc` was the missing piece.